# Counting 3-manifolds generated by identifying opposite faces of a cube

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

I'm trying to count both the total number of 3-manifolds that can be generated in this way and how many are unique 3-manifolds.

There are 4 options for identifying opposite faces: straight across, through the center of the cube, and two reflections (vertical and horizontal). Therefore there are 64 total possible identifications.

To be a 3-manifold each point needs a ball neighborhood. For this I think it is enough that all 8 vertices are identified. I tried counting how many of the 64 lead to a connected graph of the vertexes and got 38. Then out of these 38 I checked how many lead to an isomorphic graph and got 7.

My question is: Does this method work/is there an easier combinatorial way to do this?
(I thought there should be 6 unique ones although I cannot find a reference for this)

Comment: Is it also possible to join opposite faces with a quarter twist, like in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30886/homology-of-cube-with-a-twist)? You certainly get a valid topological space, but maybe it is not a $3$-manifold.

Comment: You can significantly reduce the number of cases by looking at how the octahedral groups acts on the identifications.

Comment: I mean, it's only 8 vertices.  I assume you want vertices going to vertices.  Can't you just compute them?  One simplification is that, since topologically it's just two circles on the boundary of a 3-ball, you can just compute one identification from each class of orientation-preserving and orientation-reversing for the first identification.  Note that every pair of faces has to be identified, because otherwise your space will have boundary.  Since 3-manifolds satisfy the Hauptvermutung it's sufficient to just compute.